# Flutter play store release error at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play, apk

i'm trying to publish my app to google play store But i faced this problem ,
i tried to run the app on pixel 2 emulator on android studio and it works perfectly

[image: screenshot]

here is the full report log in playstore console page

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.perfectagency.ladyin, PID: 7833
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
    at rk.f.g(Unknown Source:472)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(Unknown Source:184)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(Unknown Source:12)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.c.G(Unknown Source:106)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.c.n(Unknown Source:7)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.f.onAttach(Unknown Source:11)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Unknown Source:49)
    at androidx.fragment.app.x.c(Unknown Source:186)
    at androidx.fragment.app.x.m(Unknown Source:134)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.f0(Unknown Source:230)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.m1(Unknown Source:81)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.c0(Unknown Source:21)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.U(Unknown Source:38)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.z(Unknown Source:11)
    at androidx.fragment.app.j.c(Unknown Source:4)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(Unknown Source:20)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:193)
    at rk.f.g(Unknown Source:28)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.perfectagency.ladyin-tXBJfqHMJf1MBxpzThApTQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary(Unknown Source:13)
    at rk.f$a.b(Unknown Source:18)
    at rk.f$a.call(Unknown Source:0)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```